# confused on how my code work and want to understand the logic in it

Tags: c++

Please dont discourage this question..I am very new to c++ and really want to understand the code I work on.

```
// bintodec.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(){
        string inp;
        int dec = 0;
        char base;
        cout << "Input a number: ";
        cin >> inp;
        cout << "Input the base your number is in: ";
        cin >> base;
        for(int i = inp.length()-1, j = 0; i >= 0; i--, ++j) dec += (inp[i]-48) * pow((float)base-48, j);
        cout << "Your number in base 10 is: " << dec <<endl;
        system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

I really want to understand how this FOR LOOP runs the INPUT NUMBER and BASE, to then get an answer.

so lets say I INPUT 110 BASE 2 PRINT: 6

*How the for loop is doing it

thanks all!

Comment: please search and read a C++ tutorial.

Comment: It's really hard to tell what you're asking. Are you just wondering what a `for` loop does? It's very likely that this question will be closed, but the reason is just that it's impossible to answer without knowing what you don't understand.

Comment: @BrendanLong "I  really want to understand how this FOR LOOP runs the INPUT NUMBER and BASE, to then get an answer." impossible?

Comment: Where did this code come from??
If you don't understand how it works it is quite hard you wrote it yourself.
My impression is that you're testing a sample coming from a book, but ... what a bad book!

    (inp[i]-48)

Very good example to confuse people, especially if no-one explain where the `48` comes from.
Why didn't they wrote

    (inp[i]-'0')

making it clear that the result is `0` if imp[i] is `'0'` and `1` if `'1'` ... and so on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are taking the ASCII input values plugged into `inp`, and doing a conversion to the actual decimal equivalents by subtracting off the ASCII offset for that character.  At that point, they are merely adding each position of the input decimal raised to the power of the base for that decimal's positon.  For instance, for a number input as BASE-2, each numeral in a binary number is equivalent to the following:

```
2^2  2^1  2^0
 |    |    |
 1    1    0
```

Therefore, to convert this to BASE-10, you would add up (1*2^2) + (1*2^1) which equals 4 + 2 = 6.

If you had input a hexadecimal number (i.e, BASE-16), say 0xA5, it would look like the following:

```
16^1  16^0
  |     |
  A     5
```

That would then be equivalent to 10*16^1 + 5*16^0 which equals 160 + 5 = 165

Answer (score 2):

```
 for(int i = inp.length()-1, j = 0; i >= 0; i--, ++j)
     dec += (inp[i]-48) * pow((float)base-48, j);
```

48 is the value of `'0'`, and they are supposed to be consecutive up to `'9'` which would be 57. You should be able to work out how the job is done with that in mind.

Answer (score 0):

'0'=48, so this loop is picking up the digits starting from the end, converting the character to a number, multiplying by base raised to the correct power and summing the result.

Answer (score 0):

The 48 just converts ASCII input to its numeric representation, '0' = 48, '1' = 49, etc.  What the for loop is doing is iterating over each character entered, raising it to the base power entered, and adding it to make a decimal (base 10) answer.

If you're wondering why mathematically it works, check http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix

3657 in base 6 for example = 3x6^4 + 6x6^3 + 5x6^2 + 7x6 in decimal.